# What is this military patch with the silhouette of a pegasus on it?

Tags: 20th-century, world-war-two, military, identification

I found this patch among my grandfather's things.  I know it's a military patch of some sort because it was with his war memorabilia.  He served in the European theater during WWII, if that helps at all.  Can someone identify this unit patch?

[image: white silhouette of a Greek soldier riding a Pegasus]

Comment: I must admit, this is the most interesting question I've seen yet!

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that this would be a great category of question for this site to handle.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The "Winged Pegasus" patch is the insignia for [British Airborne Forces](http://www.parachuteregiment-hsf.org/British%20Airborne%20Forces.htm) and was specifically the divisional patch for the [6th](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6th_Airborne_Division_%28United_Kingdom%29) and [1st](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1st_Airborne_Division_(United_Kingdom)) Airborne Divisions during WW2. The 1st Airborne Division adopted the patch in May 1942, the sixth on the 14th of May 1943.

The [44th Indian Airborne Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/44th_Airborne_Division_%28India%29) also adopted a similar patch with the word 'INDIAN' underneath the design.

> Parachute wings were worn on the right shoulder above the airborne
>   forces patch of Bellerophon riding the flying horse Pegasus in their fight against the dragon Chimaera

The artwork for the patch was created by [Edward Seago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Seago).

The British Parachute regiment's mascot was a Shetland pony named Pegasus IV and the official magazine of the British Airborne forces is the "Pegasus":

[image: Pegasus - The journal of Airborne forces]

Reference:

*[Collecting British WW2 airborne militaria](http://home.tiscali.nl/nijsten/insignia.html)*

Comment: Actually, both the 1st and 6th Airborne have a Pegasus on their patch, this one looks more like the 1st Airborne's Patch. (Check out the back of the spear)

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I have updated to include the 1st AD. I think it is the same patch for both because it was the insignia of the 1st Airborne Corps of which they were both a part. I will update with some more detail on that :)

Comment: @ChristopherRayl The Pegasus BAF operated in airborne attacks previous to D-Day, most famously, the Pegasus Bridge.